# How could I sort a svelte array-store?

Tags: store, svelte

I am doing a Todo app with store.
All is good now , but i want to sort the items in the store , or maybe to show them ordered.
The store is an array , and all item in the store is an object with the keys : text,id,editing,line,checkboxed.
So "checkboxed" is a boolean  value , and i want that all the "checkboxed:true" objects would be first in the array.
how could i do it ?
Or maybe : 
how could i sort items in svelte-store-array in general ?
thanks !!!!

[link to the app](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-store-all-tuhjq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`derived`](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived) store, like:

```
const sorted = derived(todos_, todos => sortBy(todos, 'checkboxed'))
```

> Derives a store from one or more other stores. Whenever those
>   dependencies change, the callback runs.

([Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-stores-better-7h538?fontsize=14))

Answer (score 0):

another solution : 
to add that to the TodoLIst component :

```
$:sortedTodos=$customTodos
    .sort((a,b)=>b.checkboxed-a.checkboxed)
    .sort((a,b)=>a.line-b.line)
```

and work with sortedTodos variable in the "each" loop.